# How to display alertdialog when countdown timer is done android

Tags: java, android, timer, android-alertdialog

I am developing a quiz application and i want to show an `alert dialog` when the time for the quiz is up. So immediately the time is up, and `alert dialog` pops up with probably a text saying your time is up.

I did tried researching about that but nothing positive came so i was hoping to get some positive feedback here.

**below is the code i wrote for my Countdown timer.**

```
 final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1800000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("Time Spent " + String.format("%d min : %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
}

public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("Time is up");
    timerProcessing = false;
    //Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, Assesment.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}
}.start();
```

**and below is the code i wrote for the dialogue also**

```
private View.OnClickListener finishListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        //Calculate Score
        int score = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
            if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                score++;
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
        alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
                quesIndex=0;
                TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = true;
                quesIndex=0;
                TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
};
```

so question is how do i call or display the `dialog` automatically when the countdown timer is up.

thanks :)

Comment: put the alert dialog code in a function and call it once timer is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show you Alert dialog in countdown timer's onFinish() method. this method gets called on Last Tick when time is up..

```
    public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("Time is up");
    timerProcessing = false;
    //Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, Assesment.class);
    //startActivity(intent);


  AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
        alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
                quesIndex=0;
                TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = true;
                quesIndex=0;
                TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                review = false;
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i was able to answer fix it. apparently i just had to add the dialogue code to the Countdown timers onFinish() method

```
final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("Time Spent: " + String.format("%d min : %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
}

public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("Time is up");
    timerProcessing = false;
    setAnswer();
    //Calculate Score
    int score = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
        if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
            score++;
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
    alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            review = false;
            quesIndex=0;
            TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            review = true;
            quesIndex=0;
            TestActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            review = false;
            finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
}.start();
```